# Is there a way to dynamically generate an Enum in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, enums

In my application there are two tables.

#### tblEvents

- EventID
- UserID
- Date
- EventType

#### tblEventTypes

- EventTypeID
- EventName

tblEvents contains a log of events that occurred in our application. One of the columns required when adding an event to the log is the event type. The event type must be the ID of an event type stored within tblEventTypes.

In my application using Entity Framework I created a function import for a stored procedure that adds events to tblEvents. Currently I pass in an integer for event type into the method created by the function import. This just seems unreadable to me as you have no idea what the integer means without looking at the database, finding the event types table, and seeing what event it was.

I would like to create an enum to represent event types. Is there a way to create a dynamic enum that is generated based on the data in tblEventTypes? Just like how EF generates entities based on tables in the database, I would like to generate an enum based off of a table and it's current data. So adding an event type would be a matter of adding a row to tblEventTypes and then running an update in the EF designer or something that would automatically update my enum in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the EF designer for that, but you could use a [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to generate the enum.

Comment: Hmmm, I never thought about that. Interesting. I'm new to T4 templates.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Would just be nice if EF did it natively.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this type of situation quite a few times and the decision i aLways come to is that the event types should be explicitly defined and an enum created for each entry such as...

```
Public enum EventType
{
     Info = 100,
     Error = 200
 }
```

I would create a db script that creates the items in the database and keep them in sync manually.

I cant see how it would make sense to use them as a dynamic type as you would only use them in an explicit manner (such as recording an event of a certain type).

To the best of my knowledge EF does not support entity record modelling, only schemas

Comment: Right, and the idea would be to make the enum explicit, it would just be generated by the data in the database whenever I did an "update model".

I wish EF had enum support, it would be pretty cool.

Comment: Yes, when you insert a record you would write something like myEntity.EventTypeId = (int)EventType.Info;

Comment: Yeah. I know that I can create the enum manually. I'm just envisioning some code generation like EF does currently with the database schema, only this would actually read the records in the table to create the enum.

Comment: I will actually be more excited when they finally make code-first a respectable design choice. Then you could do the reverse and make the in-code enum generate an enum db table with a relationship to the tables that use it. That would be brilliant!

Comment: Thats not possible with EF alex, we still have to manage the model records manually, but yeah that would be great!

Comment: Microsoft just released a CTP of EntityFramework 4.2 that supports enum *mapping*, which is progress.  I don't think it will actually create data from the values though (but I may be wrong, haven't used it yet)